# Change value of a td depending on the checkbox status inside that td using jquery

Tags: html

There's a body tag, inside that there are many tr tags and inside each tr tag, there are many td tags, in one of the td tag there is a checkbox, the checkbox may be checked or un-checked, if the checkbox is checked I want to insert "True", if it is unchecked I want to insert "False" inside that td tag, and I want to remove the checkbox control from the td tag

HTML:

```
        <td >text-1 </td>
        <td >city-1</td>
        <td >HI</td>
        <td >&nbsp;</td>
        <td >2/20/2017 - 2/20/2018</td>
        <td ><input type="checkbox"></td>

    </tr>
    <tr >
         <td >text-2 </td>
        <td >city-2</td>
        <td >HI</td>
        <td >&nbsp;</td>
        <td >2/20/2017 - 2/20/2018</td>
        <td ><input type="checkbox" checked=checked></td>
    </tr>
    <tr >
         <td >text-3 </td>
        <td >city-3</td>
        <td >HI</td>
        <td >&nbsp;</td>
        <td >2/20/2017 - 2/20/2018</td>
        <td ><input type="checkbox" ></td>
    </tr>
```

I need to check the status of the checkbox (checked/un-checked) in the last  and insert a value True/false inside that  and remove the checkbox

Please let me know your comments.

Comment: Did you try anything?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').each(function(){
    $check = $(this);
    var text = $check.is(':checked') ? "True" : "False";
    $check.parent().append(text);
    $check.remove();
});
```

Comment: it would be great if you can add some description along with the code. So users can know what;s going on in the code.

Comment: @MukkuP then upvote  & accepting the answer is the right way to go :-)

Comment: Tried that, but since my reputation is less than 15 and hence cannot upvote